# R - keeping the leading zero in a subscript label

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis-labels

The leading zero in a x-axis label will be removed, when it has a subscript part.
How can it be retained?

Thank you.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=as.factor(cyl), y=mpg)) + 
    geom_boxplot() +  
    xlab("cyl Box01") # label without subscript


ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=as.factor(cyl), y=mpg)) + 
    geom_boxplot() +  
    xlab(expression(cyl~Box[01])) # label with subscript
```

[image: Without subscript]

[image: With subscript]

Comment: put the subscript in quotes

Comment: @rawr Post as answer?

Answer (score 0):

I use R package *latex2exp*. Using expression TeX("$\\pi_{\"00\"}=0.4$") will show two zero. For your case, changing Box[01] to Box["01"] should work.